# Google Analytics cross domain linker and referral exclusion - to IP address instead of DNS?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-sdk

G'day,

I have a client who wants to setup cross-domain tracking, but when you click through to their payment gateway you are redirected to an IP address rather than a domain name URL. I was able to find the DNS for some by using tracert on the IP address, but some of them are hosted on port 81 instead of port 80 and the URL only works if the port is specified.

Is there any way I can set up cross-domain tracking for these URLs? Will the auto linker param and referral exclusion user interface accept port 81? I cannot find this info on Google Analytics developer guides.

If anyone knows where I might look I would really appreciate it.

Thank you very much

Petra